# Regex Min Max for Expression that Allows Spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I am using this pattern:

```
^\w+( \w+)*$
```

to validate that a string is alphanumeric and may contain spaces. I can't figure out how to set a min and max though. I'd like something like this:

```
^(\w+( \w+)*){1, 50}$
```

but it's not working. What is the correct syntax?

EDIT: Sample input:
3this String is fine12

If the length of the entire string is greater than 50 though, it should not match.

Comment: Can you provide some sample inputs?  That would be easier for us to write a regex expression for.  That said, the {1,50} bit usually goes after the wildcard, e.g. `( \w*{1,50})` rather than `( \w*){1,50}`  http://www.regexpal.com/ may also be of service to you.

Comment: Are you looking for [`^(?=.{1,50}$)\w+( \w+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/fN4gG2/1)? Restrict the input string length from 1 to 50 chars? Or do you mean 1 to 50 *words*, like [`^\w+( \w+){0,49}$`](https://regex101.com/r/fN4gG2/2)? BTW, what is the programming language you are using?

Comment: Yes, this is it! `^(?=.{1,5}$)\w+( \w+)*$` to restrict the input string length from 1 to 50 chars. I am using Javascript btw.

Comment: @Draco18s, what regex flavor are you talking about? `*{1,50}` is a syntax error in every flavor I'm familiar with.  I have seen that notation somewhere, can't remember where, but it's not valid in JavaScript or any other Perl-derivative flavor.

Comment: @AlanMoore I'll take "a derp" for $200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to limit the input string length you can use a restrictive positive lookahead at the start:

```
/^(?=.{1,50}$)\w+(?: \w+)*$/
```

The input string length can range from 1 to 50 characters.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fN4gG2/3)

*Explanation:*

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{1,50}$)` - the positive lookahead that requires the string to have at least 1 character and up to 50 (note the `$` is very important here)
- `\w+` - 1 or more word characters
- `(?: \w+)*` - zero or more sequences of a space followed by 1 or more word characters
- `$` - end of string